# Add a long text in a longtblr spanning the entire width of the table

Tags: tables, margins, text, longtblr

Given the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}
    [presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt]
    {colspec = {lX},\columnwidth,colsep=4pt,hlines}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\  
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Within longtblr, I would like to add a block of text from the left margin to the right margin of the table, as following:
[image]

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge two cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  \columnwidth,
  colsep=4pt,
  hlines,
  hline{2}={0pt}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\  
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt} \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Just a small doubt... Would it be possible to remove the small vertical whitespace between ```01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}``` and ```Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismond sodale, ...``` ?

Comment: @Ommo You can adjust the space `\textbf{First}\\[-4pt]`

Comment: Sorry, I have just noticed that the text is not justfied... is there a command to justify the text here within ```\lipsum```?

Comment: @Ommo `halign=j`

Comment: Super, thanks a lot! This is exacty what I was looking for:

```\\[-4pt] \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\```