# Add a variable to longtblr, representing a vertical distance

Tags: vertical-spacing, white-space, variable, longtblr

This is a follow-up question to [Add a long text in a longtblr spanning the entire width of the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713123/add-a-long-text-in-a-longtblr-spanning-the-entire-width-of-the-table/713127?noredirect=1#comment1772420_713127). Given the following table (a longtblr):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{dcolumn,longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  \columnwidth,
  colsep=4pt,
  hlines,
  hline{2,4,6}={0pt},
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}
    \\[-4pt]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}
    \\[-4pt]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}
    \\[-4pt]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\
\end{longtblr}
```

[image]

Would it be possible to assign a variable to the vertical distance `\\[-4pt]`, maybe within the options field of longtblr? In such a way that I do not need to change it multiple times within a table with many entries/rows....

I was thinking about something like this, with a variable name "mydistance", but it does not work:

```
\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  \columnwidth,
  colsep=4pt,
  hlines,
  hline{2,4,6}={0pt},
  mydistance = -4pt,
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}
    \\[mydistance]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}
    \\[mydistance]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}
    \\[mydistance]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} {\lipsum[2]} &\\
\end{longtblr}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newlength{\foo}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\foo}{-4pt}
\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  \columnwidth,
  colsep=4pt,
  hlines,
  hline{2,4,6}={0pt},
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}
    \\[\foo]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}
    \\[\foo]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}
    \\[\foo]
    \SetCell[c=2]{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j} \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

---

If it is strictly every second row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  colsep=4pt,
  hline{odd}={solid},
  row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
  cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You nailed it! Many thanks Sam!!

Comment: @Ommo You're welcome!